# Is there a coordinate-based map widget for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a GPS-less tracking system, so I want to find a way to display the path taken.
I don't want to use something like Google Maps because I have no specific location.

I'm looking for something simple where I can pass coordinates that connect into a line along with a degree-based pointer. Other than that, it should have basic functionalities such as scrolling and zooming.

If I pass coordinates like this:

```
[0, 0]
[10, 6]
[1, 12]
etc
```

...and a direction sensor, it would display something like this:

[image: Something like this]

Has anyone heard of something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Mike Ortiz's TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView). Inside, I used a canvas and a large bitmap as the map. I used basic canvas functionalities to draw lines, and I ended up setting the pointer as a separate stationary element.